# Unable to upload high resolution images in php

Tags: php

I am trying to upload a large size images that are more than 2.5 MB that was take from IPhone. It was not uploading i do know why

Even I set the php.ini file

Increase upload size in your `php.ini`

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 24M
```

Also restarted Apache server . I dont know why this high resolution images not uploading.
Will you please help me?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know either... could you post the code?

Answer (score 1):

you have to specify the size with **MB**, not **M**

```
upload_max_filesize = 8MB
post_max_size = 8MB
```

check this [blogspot](http://mytactics.blogspot.in/2013/09/upload-large-sql-file-in-phpadmin-xampp.html)

Comment: That's not what the PHP F.A.Q says: [The available options are K (for Kilobytes), M (for Megabytes)...](http://ar2.php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes). Also, I have mine with an `M` and it works.

Comment: once when i faced the problem I used the MB and it worked ..!! so i just suggested..!! may be MB and M both will work..

Comment: Ok, so this might help him. I never saw it, but I believe you.

Comment: @user2617449 so its working now or again you are facing the same issue?

Comment: am facing th same issue. Is there is any other way?

Comment: do you get any error?? if so then whats that error and please post your code to.. and if you want to see how to upload the file in php using jquery and ajax.. you can find the working sample [here](https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0Bxxluya0NKB2VEpvMWpYQ2tKblU)